# Dynamically change the data of a bar chart with two data series

Tags: vba, dynamic, charts

I am trying to create a dynamic algorithm which adjusts the data of a bar chart with two data series each time the data base is adjusted. The code I am trying to use is as follows:

```
Sheet8.ChartObjects("PriceBarGraph").Activate
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = _
"='DeliveredPriceFunction '!$B$7:$B$62"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = Me.Range("B7", Cells(Me.Range("H3").Value + 7, 1))
```

I get a Runtime 1004 Application-defined or Object-defined error.

Any assistance would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: I think instead of using the "`me.range`" give it a try with the actual sheet name; "`sheets("yoursheetname").range(....etc`"

Comment: I unfortunately still received errors. I did however find an alternative means of achieving the same out come. I will detail this in the answer. Thanks @Philippe

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using VB code, it is possible to specify a dynamic range in Excel using the OFFSET function. The string used to specify the dynamic range is as follows:

```
=OFFSET(BarGraph_Data!$C$2,1,0,BarGraph_Data!$G$3,1)
```

The offset function works as follows:

```
=OFFSET(anchor point, rows offset, col offset, height)
```

The height is set as the number of data points which you to plot. The bar graph is then set to plot this data range, and as the height is changed in cell G3, then the range changes accordingly and therefore so does the Bar Graph.

This video assisted me in this solution:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1VnITD0rU1A